# What is the Swift equivalent for dispatch_group_create

Tags: objective-c, swift

How do I wait for several methods to be completed?

This is the objective-c solution:

```
self.dispatch_group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_notify(self.dispatch_group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
});
dispatch_group_leave(strongSelf.dispatch_group);
```

Comment: GCD still works with Swift, are you having problems with it?

Comment: it's this simple: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40476853/294884

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift is mostly compatible to Objective-C and I have no issues with this code:

```
let dispatch_group = dispatch_group_create()
dispatch_group_notify(dispatch_group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { }
dispatch_group_leave(dispatch_group)
```

There's an Apple document about transferring your Objective-C code to Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/Migration.html

Comment: I have an issue with this code — there's a semicolon in it! ;)

Comment: I shall be punished by having to write 500 lines of Objective-C!

Comment: To be specific, Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) are all C functions, not Objective-C. They are compatible because Apple has explicitly created a Swift framework for them (you can see with `import Dispatch`). On the other hand, CommonCrypto is still out in the cold.

Comment: removed semicolon to avoid confusion

Answer (score 21):

In Swift 3...

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

dispatchGroup.enter()

dispatchGroup.leave()

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {...}
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Comment: The perfect answer.